# Calculating forces in stucture

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, free-body-diagram, statics

[image]

I know how to find the reaction at a A and E and they worked just fine with me as external forces. But I am not understanding how to find the forces at joints B and D, what is the approach ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a **free body diagram**.

[image: fbd]

Replace the connections with unknown forces in the correct location and direction.

Now do the force and torque balance about any point you want, and you will get three equations to be solved for the three unknowns support forces.